# Send Authorization Token | Gatling

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I am performance testing our Enterprise API using Gatling. While testing with "Postman" I used to pass following Headers:

- API Key
- Authorization Bearer Token

It would be great if someone could help me: How can I pass "API-KEY" and "Authorization Bearer" token as a header in a Gatling request?

Please see my code below:

```
val headers_10 = Map("Content-Type" -> """application/json""")

    val httpConf = http
        .baseURL(perfProdURL)
        .acceptHeader("application/json, */*")
        .acceptCharsetHeader("UTF-8")

    val scn = scenario("Vertex API Test01")
        .exec(
            http("request_1")
            .post("/details/orders")
            .headers(headers_10)
            .check(status.is(200))
            .body(RawFileBody("/Users/z063011/Sunil/test.json")).asJSON)
```

Comment: How about adding it to your already defined headers map: `val headers_10 = Map("Content-Type" -> """application/json""", "API-KEY" -> "your_api_key", "Authorization Bearer" -> "auth_bearer")`?

Comment: Yep did that... Working good

Comment: Awesome! I added an answer, feel free to vote up and accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can add additional fields to your already defined headers map like this:

```
val headers_10 = Map("Content-Type" -> """application/json""", "API-KEY" -> "your_api_key", "Authorization Bearer" -> "auth_bearer")
```

You might also want to check out the [docs on headers](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_request/#headers).

Comment: This is my first time I am using gatling and I need to use oauth2 Bearer token to each call.  When I use your solution for header map, I got error "Header name cannot contain the following prohibited characters: =,;: \t\r\n\v\f: Authorization Bearer". I am able to store the token in a variable and when I pass it to next call I got this error. Here is my `code val headers_10 = Map("Content-Type" -> """application/json""", "Authorization Bearer" -> token)`

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is older and answered, but as an alternative you can also add your Bearer token as follows:

```
val token: String = getTokenFunction()

val httpConf = http
  .baseUrl(myUrlForLoadTests)
  .authorizationHeader(s"Bearer $token")
  .acceptHeader("application/json, */*")
  .acceptCharsetHeader("UTF-8")
```